# SDN RYU Snort integration with Mininet

Tags: snort

I have created test-bed with SDN Ryu with Snort IDS and Mininet, I can only log packets of DDoS attack around 15 to 20 but want to increase features like KDD 99  to run Machine Learning. Thanks Raja

Comment: Could you please provide more detail/an example

Comment: Many thanks Liam, As I mentioned that I created mininet topology to remotely connect with RYU server in Ubuntu, but RYU recieve all log file data from Snort IDS sensor installed with promisc mode of s1-eth1 ovs switch, I run LOIC DDoS tool for flooding from host h1 to catch data , but its very limited around 15 to 20 features,   I used customised single signature rule for that.    Thanks